# Sitemap in Django - Titles don't show in google search

Tags: django, sitemap

I have followed the steps in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#a-simple-example) and it seems to be working as expected.

I have got an automated sitemap generated: https://duelify.com/sitemap.xml

Yet somehow there is no way to specify the title.

If I search in google for my site: `site:duelify.com` and scroll down I see the main site's title for every link:

> **Duelify | Duel Your Friends & Foes**
>
> https://duelify.com/topics/discuss/2/vegetarian-diet/

That doesn't look right.

If I try this with Stackoverflow:

`site:stackoverflow.com django`

Each entry has a proper title.

How could I achieve that? It is not clear from the given site map [references](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-class-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title displayed in Google search results has nothing to do with the sitemap.

Use meta (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) and title tags:

```
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Your page description">
<title>Your page title</title>
</head>
```

And don't forget to set proper HTML heading tags.

Comment: Thanks. SO what I need in this case is `<meta name="description" content="MyTitle?">`